# Copy deedle frame to excel

Tags: excel, f#, deedle

My goal is to efficiently copy a [deedle frame](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle) to excel in F#.
I have never worked with excel from F#. I have been inspired by [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297098%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

This is my code:

```
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
/// Export data frame to excel
let exportFrameToExcel (frame: Frame<DateTime, string>) (x,y) = 
    // Run Excel as a visible application
    let app = new ApplicationClass(Visible = true) 
    // Create new file and get the first worksheet
    let workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet) 
    // Note that worksheets are indexed from one instead of zero
    let worksheet = (workbook.Worksheets.[1] :?> Worksheet) 

    let mutable col = y+1
    for key in frame.ColumnKeys do
        worksheet.Cells.[x, col] <- key
        col <- col + 1
    for i = 0 to frame.RowCount-1 do
        let row = frame.GetRowAt(i)
        let rowKey = frame.GetRowKeyAt(i)
        worksheet.Cells.[i+x+1, y] <- rowKey
        for j = 0 to frame.ColumnCount-1 do
            let value = row.GetAtAs<float>(j)
            worksheet.Cells.[i+x+1, j+y+1] <- value
```

It is slow and may crash if I touch the excel window while data is being copied.
I am sure there is plenty of room for improvement, for example I think `ApplicationClass` should be instead turned to `visible`only when the data has been copied.

I would appreciate some guidance / help in doing this task in an efficient and idiomatic way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At BlueMountain (where we did most of the work on Deedle), they actually had a utility for passing data to Excel. We wanted to include this in Deedle, but never managed to publish it, because it would take some time to polish & document things.

We actually put the source code on GitHub (as part of one of my demo talks), so you [can get it here](https://github.com/tpetricek/Documents/blob/master/Talks%202013/FsLab%20Showcase%20%28Seattle%29/code/Excel/Excel.fsx).
Using this, you should be able to just write:

```
xl?A1 <- deedleFrame
```

There is a lot more you can do - have a look at the members of the `Xl` type.

Also, we originally used [NetOffice](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/) which is an easier to use wrapper for the Excel COM interop - the referenced sample is not using it, but it is probably a good idea.